# Large gaps between home screen icons, can it be reduced?

Tags: home-screen, samsung-galaxy-s-3

The icons on the Samsung Galaxy S3 have large gaps between them, enough so that if they were moved closer together you could fit at least one more row and maybe one more column. Is there a way to change this?

**This is what it looks like:**

[image: Samsung Galaxy S3 Screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK there's no built-in method to achieve that personalization.

I would go with [Apex Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anddoes.launcher&hl=en) by Android Does available from Google Play Store, to use with Android 4.0+, it's free and among the features you'll find:

> - **Customizable homescreens and grid size**
> - Scrollable dock
> - Infinite & elastic scrolling
> - Customizable app and folder icons
> - Multiple drawer styles
> - Drawer apps sorting
> - Hide apps from the drawer
> - Enjoy homescreen gestures
> - Backup/restore settings and data

**APEX Launcher Homescreen Settings:**

[image: APEX Launcher Homescreen Settings]

Other features can be found if you go [PRO](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anddoes.launcher.pro&feature=more_from_developer).

Comment: Duh, I didn't think to look into the settings for the custom launcher. I use Go Launcher and it does this a little bit too (albeit not as well as APEX). Thanks!

Comment: I accepted this a couple of days ago, I don't know why it didn't stick... oh well, accepted again.